# A uniform upper bound for Fredholm index of Laplace quasi-operators on a compact parallelizable manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, index-theory

Assume  that  $M$ is  a  compact  parallelizable  manifold. Is there an upper bound  for the   absolute value of Fredholm index of all operators in the form  $D=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial^2/\partial{X_i^2}$  where $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$ is  a global smooth frame?

Comment: $M$ is connected I guess?

Comment: @ThomasRot  Yes we assume that $M$ is connected. But even if $M$  is not connected  it  can not have infinite number of connected component.

Comment: Search of "quasi Laplace operator" in Google brings "Laplace quasi-operator".

Comment: @user64494  thanks for your edit.